# How to use Haskell's bitwise functions on unsigned types (e.g., `Word8`, `Word16`)?

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation

What (if anything) can I do in order to be able to use functions from `Data.Bits` (e.g., `clearBit`, `setBit`) on unsigned types, namely `Word8` and `Word16`?  At the moment, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Word8’
```

I'm going to be performing a large volume of these operations so `fromIntegral` is not ideal.

Any suggestions?

**Update 2:**
This is what I needed:

```
testBitW :: (Bits a, Integral b) => a -> b -> Bool
testBitW a i = testBit a (fromIntegral i)
```

**Update:**

Am pulling my hair out trying to get the following to compile.  It's puzzling that the same code works fine if entered directly into GHCi (running `:t` gives the same implied type signature as per my definition below).

```
testBitW :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> Bool
testBitW a i = testBit (fromInteger $ toInteger a) (fromInteger $ toInteger i)
```

I keep getting the following two errors.  Using `fromIntegral` in place of `fromInteger $ toInteger` results in the same errors...

```
test.hs:119:16:
    Could not deduce (Bits a0) arising from a use of ‘testBit’
    from the context (Integral a1, Integral a)
      bound by the inferred type of
               testBitW :: (Integral a1, Integral a) => a -> a1 -> Bool
      at test.hs:119:1-78
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Bits Word16 -- Defined in ‘GHC.Word’
      instance Bits Word32 -- Defined in ‘GHC.Word’
      instance Bits Word64 -- Defined in ‘GHC.Word’
      ...plus 9 others
    In the expression:
      testBit (fromInteger $ toInteger a) (fromInteger $ toInteger i)
    In an equation for ‘testBitW’:
        testBitW a i
          = testBit (fromInteger $ toInteger a) (fromInteger $ toInteger i)

test.hs:119:25:
    Could not deduce (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘fromInteger’
    from the context (Integral a1, Integral a)
      bound by the inferred type of
               testBitW :: (Integral a1, Integral a) => a -> a1 -> Bool
      at test.hs:119:1-78
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 11 others
    In the expression: fromInteger
    In the first argument of ‘testBit’, namely
      ‘(fromInteger $ toInteger a)’
    In the expression:
      testBit (fromInteger $ toInteger a) (fromInteger $ toInteger i)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing `Data.Word` will bring instances of `Bits Word8` etc. into scope.

Although from your error it looks like you're talking about the second argument to e.g. `setBit`, which is specified to be `Int`. If you want to specify the bit offset with `Word`s, you'll have to use `fromInteger . toInteger`. You can probably abstract it out somehow, depending on the context.

### Update

The errors of the form "could not deduce..." are, in this case, *strong hints* from the compiler about the needed type signature. Here's how to work it out.

First, what's the type of `testBit`?

```
> :t testBit
testBit :: Bits a => a -> Int -> Bool
```

So we know the second argument needs to be an `Int` (not an `Integer`!), but the first argument can be any type with a `Bits` instance. The most general conversion to an `Int` is via `Integer`:

```
> :t \x -> (fromInteger . toInteger $ x) :: Int
\x -> (fromInteger . toInteger $ x) :: Int
  :: Integral s => s -> Int
```

Therefore we need to know one thing about each parameter to our `testBitW` function: the first needs to be an instance of `Bits`, and the second an instance of `Integral`. (We *don't* need to convert the first parameter to an `Int`, and in fact doing so is almost certainly an error.)

When in doubt, we can let the compiler *infer* the constraints, which will usually give you the most general type signature:

```
> let testBitW a i = testBit a (fromInteger . toInteger $ i)
> :t testBitW
testBitW :: (Bits a, Integral s) => a -> s -> Bool
```

And that's the type signature to put in your source file.

Comment: It seems like there's no getting around conversions.  That said, I find it really odd that I can get the code (per your suggestion) to compile if entered directly in `GHCi` but that I can't get it to compile if loaded from a file...  Do you know if I need any special settings/pragmas?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show you how to work out the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the second code snippet doesn't work is that you don't have `(... Bits a, Bits b) =>` as part of the constraint. `Integral` doesn't imply `Bits`. In that case, you also don't need to convert the first argument at all and you just need `fromIntegral` for the second argument (like your first code snippet).

`testBit` requires its first argument to be of a type that is an instance of `Bits`, and you can't determine that from `Integral` constraints since those two type classes are essentially independent of each other.

Also, I suspect those `fromIntegral` calls will have minimal run time cost.

Incidentally, `fromIntegral` is [defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Real.html#fromIntegral):

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger
```

Although, there are `RULES` that optimize that definition out some common cases and there are more `fromIntegral` `RULES` for these particular cases in [`GHC.Word`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Word.html) (which is imported by `Data.Word`).

I believe the reason that the code works in GHCi is this part `(fromInteger $ toInteger a)` defaulted to a more specific type. GHCi has more aggressive type defaulting than GHC (especially for numeric types like these). If I disable the numeric defaulting in GHCi with `default ()` and then try to define `testBitW` as you have it in the second example, it looks like it gives the same error.